# How to have gnu make treat intermediate files as out of date

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I've been following http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine to create a Makefile that will generate a dependency list too, so the list of header files a `.o` target depends on (from the related `.c` file) is automatically generated.

The Makefile I have ended up with is

```
DEPDIR := .deps
$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR))
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

INCDIR = ../includes

CFLAGS = -I$(INCDIR)

CC = gcc

SRCS = main.c chunk.c memory.c

COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

%.o: %.c
%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS))))
```

running `make main.o` generates `main.o` and `.deps/main.d` as expected, and changing one of the header files included in `main.c` causes `main.o` to be out of date and regenerated as desired.
However, `main.o` should also be out of date if `.deps/main.d` does not exist, but deleting `.deps/main.d` doesn't cause `make` to see `main.o` as out of date.

What needs to be changed to make deleting `.deps/main.d` cause `make` to see `main.o` as out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been meaning to update my blog post.  You need to ensure that the dependency files are listed as prerequisites somewhere so they're not considered intermediate.  Change this line:

```
include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS))))
```

to something like:

```
ALLDEPS := $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS)))

build-deps: $(ALLDEPS)
.PHONY: build-deps

include $(wildcard $(ALLDEPS))
```

I'm not 100% sure why these are considered intermediate and yet make doesn't delete them; I'll have to look into it more closely.

Comment: That worked great, thank you. Now deleting a .d file causes the corresponding .o (and therefore the .d) to be rebuilt. So once the files are listed as a prerequisite somewhere else make doesn't consider them to be intermediate, and therefore doesn't always assume they are up to date? I'll have to play around with this a bit more. Fantastic blog post by the way, and great to get a response on here from the author!

Comment: Correct.  Any target listed explicitly anywhere in the makefile (as either a target or a prerequisite) is sufficient to prevent it from being considered intermediate.  Basically it tells make "someone may want to look at this, so don't delete it".